# Daydream Controller Orientation

Tags: three.js, aframe, webvr, daydream

I'd like to draw a primitive where the Raycaster or the remote is pointing. I am searching for some kind of "get Orientation" method in aframe or three.js. Is there a simple and fast way to get the world coordinates, where my controller is pointing?
Thanks in advance!

Update:
Here's the code:

HTML: 
[...]

```
<a-entity id="remote" daydream-controller raycaster="objects: .selectable">
<a-cone id="ray" color="cyan" position="0 0 -2" rotation="-90 0 0" radius bottom="0.005" radius-top="0.001" height="4"></a-cone>
<a-box id="position-guide" visible="false" position="0 0 -2"></a-box>
</a-entity
```

Here is the javascript to the HTML:

```
var rayEl = document.querySelector('#remote');
rayEl.addEventListener(
var rayElDirection = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,-1);
rayEl.object3D.getWorldDirection(rayElDirection);
console.log("Raycaster Direction: " + rayElDirection);
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting daydream data loaded to an Object3D, [I found a PR that i'm not sure is in the current build](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/3b8f7fa89d430eb7ed7fd1f4f342a0d503349b12/examples/js/vr/DaydreamController.js), but you could probably just load this as its own script, so long as it loads after three.js.

Once you have that, you can get the orientation of the controller - since it extends THREE.Object

You can check out [Object3D's documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/core/Object3D) to find available functions. THREE.Object.getWorldDirection() would give you a vector of where the Daydream controller is pointed.

Combine that with .getWorldPosition(), and you could, for example put a representation of the controller at that position in the scene for debugging purposes.

Comment: Thanks! I tried the getWorldDirection() function, but it seems to give me the current position of the controller, not the direction it is pointing at. I tried different ways already, but nothing seems to work. When I tried to get the information out of the quaternion, the values didn't seem to represent the actual direction either. 

I tried the following with the direction: 

`var rayElDirection = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,-1);
        rayEl.object3D.getWorldDirection(rayElDirection);`

But as I mentioned it seems to only get the current remote position.

Comment: I dont know what rayEl is. Can you link to the implementation that you're using to access the daydream controller?

If you're loading data into an object3d wrong, then it won't work. It also might be rotated 90 degrees or whatever which means you might need to rotate, but it should be a unit vector pointing along the positive Z-axis.

daydreamcontroller.getworlddirection() will return a vector that points along the positive axis of that object. That's just what the function does. getworldposition() on the otherhand will return the position of that Object3D. Just share the code or cant help